# Does anyone know how to getr this background effect with css?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a site with a similar background to this website's.

http://citymob.co.za

Does anyone know how it is done?

Comment: Which background effect are you talking about? The bod7 bg, or a background of an element?

Comment: The background where a grid is overlain on the city photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the page backround, it's done by using a large background image n one absolutely positioned div that covers the entire screen, with another absolutely positioned div with a repeating dots background layered over the top.

If you're talking about the see through effect of the main elements on top of the two bg images, this can be done with either `opacity: .5;/*value*/;` or `background: rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)/*grey half opaque*/`.

You can take a look for yourself by hitting F12 (in a good browser, IE's dev tools are shamefully bad) and taking a look at the markup and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, take a look at the source of the web site and analyze the code. (in your browser, right click --> view source)

The web page's container uses class bg9, located in an external .css file, which refers to some image. Usually websites use external images as backgrounds for good, appealing aesthetic looks.